# Opening the main frame (application window) from a second frame in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, back-button

I am developing a new Login App in java, I'm just starting to learn java and I want to create a button to go back to the main frame(like a log out button) but for some reason setVisible() is not working for the main frame. Anybody can clear this up for me? Would be really helpful! Thanks.

Comment: Could you share your not working code with us to have a better look on your problem?

Comment: btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     
     dispose();
     Login log = new Login();
     log.setVisible(true);
    }

Comment: Please look at the tag descriptions as you select them. IBM Mainframe removed.

Comment: It says the method it's Undefined for the type Login..

Answer (score 1):

You should use a JDialog for the login popup and use the setVisible after the login is successful.